# Typescript <T = keyof Interface> to discriminate return value of interface

Tags: typescript

I have an interface `DocumentEventMap` that I'm working with, and want to index on it based on another argument. Something like

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";

export function useDocumentListener<T = keyof DocumentEventMap>(
  listener: (event: DocumentEventMap[T]) => any,
  {
    eventType,
    key,
    capture = false,
  }: {
    eventType: T;
    key?: string;
    capture?: boolean;
  }
) {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener(eventType, listener, { capture });
    return () => document.removeEventListener(eventType, listener, { capture });
  }, [listener, key, eventType, capture]);
}
...
useDocumentListener(event => {
  // event inferred as type KeyboardEvent
}, {eventType: "keydown"});
```

I keep getting very strange errors when doing this.
[DocumentEventMap key error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwXAN.png)[eventType not accepted as keyof DocumentEventMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8OSi.png)

I tried to change it to  and got a different set of errors stemming from T being a superset of keyof DocumentEventMap, and  doesn't seem to be correct syntax. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: change `= keyof DocumentEventMap` to `extends keyof DocumentEventMap`

Comment: Tobias, Seems I didn't write it there properly, but I tried that. I got a different set of errors stemming from T being a superset of keyof DocumentEventMap.

Comment: I got no error here after changing the line: https://tsplay.dev/N71OEW

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the errors you are getting?